# How to divide and iterate SQL query result into chunks in Python, is it going to decrease the execution time if I have millons of records?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, bigdata, impala

I am using impala as database and trying to fetch 25 millions records, but it is taking too much time i.e. approx. 40 minutes while I am executing it from Python. I was thinking to divide the entire query result into chunks and iterate each chunks one by one it this is going to boost the performance?

But how would I do that?

Comment: Are you using Impala JDBC with your python?

Comment: no I am using pyodbc i.e.pyodbc.connect(connection_str, autocommit=True)